# jQuery toggle - how to enable fade effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, font-awesome

I'm a student and learning javascript. I am doing a sample project called ToDo list, in that I am doing small animation called fade toggle. I am using it with font awesome, but its not working.

I am not sure what is wrong in that, I have highlighted the toggle code in below with asterisks. Please help me to solve this problem.

**HTML For my todo list**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/css/todo.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "asset/js/lib/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id = "container">
       **<h1>To-Do list <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>**
       <input type = "text" placeholder = "Add New ToDo" maxlength="40">

       <ul>
          **<li ><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span> go to class</li>
          <li ><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></i></span> wdh dog</li>
          <li ><span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></i></span> eat food</li>**
       </ul>
    </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "asset/js/todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**css for my todo list**

```
h1{
    background: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.fa-plus{
    float: right;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: Roboto;
}

body{
    background: #2BC0E4;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

li{
    background: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #666;
}

li:nth-child(2n){
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

li span{
    background: #e74c3c;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition:0.2s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}

li:hover span{
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

input {
    color:  #2980b9;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

input:focus{
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px solid  #2980b9;
    outline: none;
}

#container {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
    width: 360px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.completed {
    color:  gray;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

**javaScript for my todo list**

```
// check off specific todos by clicking
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

//click on x to delete todos without event bubbling
$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text'").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        //grabbing new todo text from input
        var todoText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        //create a new li and add to ul
        $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>")
    }
});

**$(".fa-plus").click(function(){
    $("input[type='text'").fadeToggle()
});**
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten a closing bracket in your selection:

```
$(".fa-plus").click(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle()
});
```

Think that might solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your help i did the changes but still i cant able to fadeToggle when i click on plus sign

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to toggle the fade on? Also, could you put the body of the fadeToggle() function in your code above?